# Can't install packages in Umbraco

Tags: numpy, umbraco

I am trying to add a package to my Umbraco website. As we all know, usually there will be an option to install new packages under developer/Packages, but here I can't see anything under the packages section. What's wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly which version of Umbraco you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grant privileges for the IIS_IUSRS user to the `C:\Windows\Temp` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. 
Make sure the package that you're trying to upload is in a zip file.
I'm using Umbraco version 7.5.11.